# How safe are Interlocked.Exchange?

Tags: c#, multithreading, interlocked

Beeing a threading noob, I'm trying to find a way w/o locking objects that allows me to enqueue a threadpool task, in such way that it has a max degree of parallelism = 1.

Will this code do what I think it does?

```
private int status;
private const int Idle = 0;
private const int Busy = 1;

private void Schedule()
{
    // only schedule if we idle
    // we become busy and get the old value to compare with
    // in an atomic way (?)
    if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref status, Busy) == Idle)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Run);
    }
}
```

That is, in a threadsafe way enqueue the `Run` method if the status is `Idle`.
It seems to work fine in my tests, but since this is not my area, I'm not sure.

Comment: It is okay, assuming that Run() knows what job to pick in a thread-safe way.  You need a true lock for that.  Setting it back to Idle is the more critical operation since you need to be absolute sure that happens even if the thread is aborted and you're likely to want to get another waiting job running right away.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on the right track then, the run method picks it's job from a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will do what you want. It will never allow you to get a return value of Idle when in fact status is Busy, and it will set status to Busy in the same operation, with no chance of a conflict. So far so good.

However, if you're using a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` later on, why do you even do this? Why do you use a ThreadPool to enqueue Run over and over again, instead of just having a single thread continually take data from the concurrent queue using TryDequeue?

In fact, there is a producer-consumer collection that is specifically designed for this, the `BlockingCollection<T>`. Your consumer thread would just call `Take` (with a cancellation token if necessary - probably a good idea) and that either returns a value as in `ConcurrentQueue<T>;` *or* if no value is available, blocks the thread until there is something to take. When some other thread adds an item to the collection, it will notify as many consumers as it has data for (in your case, no need for anything complex, since you only have one consumer).

That means you only have to handle starting and stopping a single thread, which will run an "infinite" cycle, which will call `col.Take`, while the producers call `col.Add`.

Of course, this assumes you have .NET 4.0+ available, but then again, you probably do, since you're using `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.

Comment: The reason I enque to the threadpool is that this is located in the mailbox class of my actor lib, so there can be thousands or millions of mailboxes processing messages cuncurrently, and since alot of them will be idle alot of the time, I use the thread pool to schedule the ones that are actually active right now

Comment: Which is the reason I don't use the BlockingCollection, since it is blocking.. I can't waste thread resources like that in my case.

Comment: @RogerAlsing: I haven't tried it in practice, but it shouldn't be blocking for adding if you're usign the constructor without bounded capacity. In that case, it should work as a relatively simple wrapper around `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, which inherently supports notifications. All in all, it shouldn't use locking at all (instead, both concurrent queue and blocking collection rely on atomic operations using Interlocked, just like you do), and it *shouldn't* be blocking for writing, only for reading. But of course, in the end it all comes down to profiling :)

Comment: @Luaan: You are correct: an unbounded BlockingCollection doesn't block.